# Visual Studio not detect some User Controls and Forms cause me can not open that control designer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I found some User Controls and Forms display as Plain code. It still display .Designer.cs and .resx but no option to open designer. Any suggest please

- These controls can open designer in previously
- VS 2022 Community
- Used .NET Core 6

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution myself. The problem Forms and Controls not define in project file. Just add following code then reload project

```
<Compile Update="YourForm.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>

<Compile Update="YourUC.cs">
    <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as a solution, so the question is solved.